# How to update session values in joomla?

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a form.Now I want to save it's value to session, So I have set the session value when the form submitted like below.

```
if(JRequest::getVar('from')=='watches'){
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $post = JRequest::get('post');
    $session->set('wt_postdata',$post);
}
```

So the value are set to session variable `wt_postdata`. That's fine. Now I want that if user again visit the same form ,even if the current session not destroyed, user again submitted the same form with the new value ,so the new value will override the old value which stored previously. I want to know that is it possible to update/modify the session value?

If not is there any alternative by that I can temporarily stored the post data for later uses?

Please help.

Comment: You can just override the session value

Comment: @ValentinDespa how can I override the session value?

Comment: Just set it again. It will override the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

I understand it is an old post but I thought to share the answer in case someone is looking for it.

In Joomla to Update the Session value you need to set the same variable name with the new value for example:

```
$session=JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('var1','x');
$session->set('var1','y');
```

Now, **Var 1** is : **y**